# SQLite connection pooling with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: .net, database, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate, connection-pooling

Is there a way to setup SQLite connection **pooling** using Fluent NHibernate configuration?

E.g. equivalent of `DataSource=:memory:` would be:

```
var sessionFactory = Fluently
     .Configure()
     .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory)
     (etc.)
```

Is there something eqivalent to `"Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1;"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to specify a connection string when using Fluent NHibernate (or NHibernate without fluent for that matter) in the [NHibernate configuration](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/archive/2008/08/18/fluent-nhibernate-configuration.aspx) so you can just enable connection pooling in the [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite) as you would if you were using ADO.NET.

Comment: Thanks, it's just that for SQLite you only need to specify a file name to get it running (`SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile(SQLiteDbFileName)`), or (`.InMemory'`) to get a in-memory db. So I thought that they might have added all sorts of fluent methods for configuring all that other stuff also. Never mind, it's just for testing anyway.

Comment: `UsingFile` is just a shortcut for `ConnectionString(string)` with a pre-build connection string. You should just be able to call `ConnectionString` with whatever you want as the argument.